# How do C/C++ optimizations affect volatile variables?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I'm having some issue with some code (see below). When all optimization are off (-O0) the code behaves as i would expect however when I turn on optimization the code does not perform as I would expect. So I'm posting here to see if someone sees a reason why the code would operate differently (incorrectly) when optimizations are on. Let me explain what the code is doing...

TPM0->CNT is a timer register and is of volatile uint32_t type. When TPM0->CNT reaches it's maximum value and rolls over an interrupt is generated. Within this interrupt sg_CpuCount is incremented by the number of timer cycles that have elapsed since the last interrupt.

The GetCpuCount function's job is to return the instantaneous count (i.e. sg_CpuCount + TPM0->CNT) however because interrupts can happen at any moment and the timer does not stop care must be taken when reading/computing this. The two components are read and then the first component is once again tested to see if it changed. If it changed its known a interrupt fired in between the first and 2nd reading and the process is repeated, however if they are the same it is known no interrupt occurred and the addition of the components is returned.

Is the logic sound? Is optimization generating bad code? any insights? Thanks in advance!

edit: I should mention the behavior I notice when optimizations are on. Basically subsequent calls to GetCpuCount are not always monotonic increasing like they are when optimizations are off. That is later calls to GetCpuCount might return a smaller number than previous calls - that should not be possible.

edit2: I should mention the micro this code runs on is a 32bit architecture (and I'm using 64bit values). I still think it should be ok but it is a point to think about.

```
static volatile int64_t sg_CpuCount;

void TPM0_IRQHandler(void)
{
   TPM0->SC |= TPM_SC_TOF(1); //clear interrupt flag
   sg_CpuCount += CPU_CLOCK / TICKRATE_HZ;
}

int64_t GetCpuCount(void)
{
   for (;;) {
      int64_t tmpCpuCount = sg_CpuCount;
      uint32_t tmpCnt = TPM0->CNT;
      if (tmpCpuCount == sg_CpuCount) {
         return tmpCpuCount + tmpCnt;
      }
   }
}
```

edit3: adding asm

optimized (-0s)

```
GetCpuCount:
.LFB36:
    .loc 2 80 0
    .cfi_startproc
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 4, -16
    .cfi_offset 5, -12
    .cfi_offset 6, -8
    .cfi_offset 14, -4
.LBB2:
    .loc 2 82 0
    ldr r4, .L20
    .loc 2 83 0
    ldr r6, .L20+4
.L18:
    //int64_t tmpCpuCount = sg_CpuCount;
    ldr r0, [r4]
    ldr r1, [r4, #4]
    //uint32_t tmpCnt = TPM0->CNT;
    ldr r5, [r6, #4]
    //if (tmpCpuCount == sg_CpuCount) {
    ldr r2, [r4]
    ldr r3, [r4, #4]
    cmp r0, r2
    bne .L18
    cmp r1, r3
    bne .L18
    //return tmpCpuCount + tmpCnt;
    movs    r0, r5
    movs    r1, #0
.LBE2:
    .loc 2 88 0
    @ sp needed
.LBB3:
    .loc 2 85 0
    adds    r0, r0, r2
    adcs    r1, r1, r3
.LBE3:
    .loc 2 88 0
    pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
.L21:
    .align  2
.L20:
    .word   sg_CpuCount
    .word   1073971200
    .cfi_endproc
```

non optimized (-00)

```
GetCpuCount:
.LFB36:
    .loc 2 80 0
    .cfi_startproc
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 16
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r4, r7, lr}
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 12
    .cfi_offset 4, -12
    .cfi_offset 7, -8
    .cfi_offset 14, -4
    sub sp, sp, #20
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    add r7, sp, #0
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 7
.L19:
.LBB2:
    //int64_t tmpCpuCount = sg_CpuCount;
    ldr r3, .L21
    ldr r4, [r3, #4]
    ldr r3, [r3]
    str r3, [r7, #8]
    str r4, [r7, #12]
    //uint32_t tmpCnt = TPM0->CNT;
    ldr r3, .L21+4
    ldr r3, [r3, #4]
    str r3, [r7, #4]
    //if (tmpCpuCount == sg_CpuCount) {
    ldr r3, .L21
    ldr r4, [r3, #4]
    ldr r3, [r3]
    ldr r0, [r7, #8]
    cmp r0, r3
    bne .L19
    ldr r0, [r7, #12]
    cmp r0, r4
    bne .L19
    //return tmpCpuCount + tmpCnt;
    ldr r3, [r7, #4]
    movs    r1, r3
    movs    r3, #0
    movs    r2, r3
    ldr r3, [r7, #8]
    ldr r4, [r7, #12]
    adds    r3, r3, r1
    adcs    r4, r4, r2
.LBE2:
    .loc 2 88 0
    movs    r0, r3
    movs    r1, r4
    mov sp, r7
    add sp, sp, #20
    @ sp needed
    pop {r4, r7, pc}
.L22:
    .align  2
.L21:
    .word   sg_CpuCount
    .word   1073971200
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Please add the `main` function for completeness.

Comment: Do you really want volatile and not `std::atomic` instead.

Comment: well this is actually C code and not C++ code. Also I'm not sure hot std::atomic interacts with interrupts.

Comment: Do you *need* `sg_CpuCount` to be an `int64_t`? I'd try with it being a `volatile sig_atomic_t` instead.

Comment: The main function is not really helpful to this. I think I edited the post with additional information that you may be looking for.

Comment: If you're using counters larger than the natural word size, that can easily cause problems. Have you examined the assembler output with and without optimization? Both those functions could be interesting, and `+=` on a larger-than-word type is always likely to be problematic.

Comment: Show us the generated assembly code. The two functions are sufficiently simple so the generated assembly code should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: It's very possible the updates to `sg_CpuCount` are not occurring atomically.

Comment: `main` function *is* relevant. Please include it. MCVE is required for any "why my code is not working" questions.

Comment: I'll get the asm - I need to figure out how to generate the intermediate files...

Comment: FWIW, this seems mechanism seems like overkill compared to e.g. `tmp = sg_CpuCount; return tmp + TMP0->CNT;` (the non-atomicity would affect it either way).

Comment: This code is part of a larger project. main just calls a bunch of init function not related to this portion of the code.

Comment: Wait - this logic is weird full-stop!  You're doing `sg_CpuCount + TMP0->CNT`, which only makes sense if they're in the same units.  Thus your ISR should be incrementing by MAX_VALUE_OF_COUNTER.  So this only makes sense of CPU_CLOCK / TICKRATE_HZ equals that value.

Comment: TMP0->CNT counts from 0 to CPU_CLOCK / TICKRATE_HZ - 1 and then rolls over. So CPU_CLOCK / TICKRATE_HZ is the number of counts per interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a 32bit machine you cannot guarantee 64bit operations to be atomic. Due to optimizations timings may shift. And never ever call the function with interrupts disabled.

```
static volatile uint32_t sg_CpuCount;

void TPM0_IRQHandler(void)
{
   TPM0->SC |= TPM_SC_TOF(1); //clear interrupt flag
   sg_CpuCount++; //count interrupts
}

int64_t GetCpuCount(void)
{
   for (;;) {
      uint32_t tmpCpuCount = sg_CpuCount;
      uint32_t tmpCnt = TPM0->CNT;
      if (tmpCpuCount == sg_CpuCount) {
         return (int64_t)tmpCpuCount * CPU_CLOCK / TICKRATE_HZ + tmpCnt;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I realize 64 bit operation will not be atomic, but that is why the if statement in GetCpuCount function to verify sg_CpuCount has not changed from the first reading.

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing the ASM for optimized and non optimized code I noticed one main difference. One loads the 64bit int high word first and the other does low word first. So I believe user5329483 is correct and I'll explain the exact sequence that could cause the problem...

```
read sg_CpuCount low
read sg_CpuCount high
read TPM0->CNT
read sg_CpuCount low
***interrupt***
read sg_CpuCount high
compare first sg_CpuCount with second sg_CpuCount (equal!!!!!)
```

Since the increment of sg_CpuCount in the interrupt may only change the lower word the above sequence fails to detect the interrupt happened.

The non optimized code is as follows:

```
read sg_CpuCount high
read sg_CpuCount low
read TPM0->CNT
read sg_CpuCount high
***interrupt***
read sg_CpuCount low
compare first sg_CpuCount with second sg_CpuCount (**NOT** equal!!!!!)
```

This code correctly detected the interrupt happened.

So the optimization did in fact change the code - however both code gens are equally valid from the perspective of the compiler. So the answer is to either explicitly define the order of operations by splitting the 64bit int into 2 32bit variables or better yet just use user5329483's suggested code.

edit: unfortunately 32bits is not enough to run for long enough times. Anyway the problem is well understood now.

Comment: Not really sure about this. In your first example you didn't detected the interrupt, but the function still returns a valid value: `sg_CpuCount + TPM0->CNT` from before the interrupt.  What type is TPM0?

Comment: TPM0's is a struct of many CPU registers CNT is volatile uint32_t. Yes, you are correct that the first example can return a valid value even though it fails to detect the interrupt - but not always... I believe there is one more component at play here - interrupt latency. I found out it is possible to read TPM0->CNT as 0 or 1 (i.e. rollover) just prior to the interrupt executing . My problem only happens under this condition. So in the first example CNT is read (as 0 or 1) and sg_CpuCount low is read prior to the interrupt, but sg_CpuCount is incorrect because it hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Do you see the timer-overflow flag set in GetCpuCount()? It should immediately trigger an interrupt and should be cleared in the ISR, so you don't see it. If yes why? Globally disabled interrupts?

Comment: I didn't investigate if the flag is observable in the GetCpuCount function. But after the flag asserts the cpu may execute 1 more instruction before the interrupt process begins. By placing a single asm("nop") instruction just prior to the if statement fixed all issues. I am looking for documentation on the interrupt latency timing to determine if one nop will guarantee correct operation.